# How to group duplicate item keys

Tags: android, dictionary, kotlin

I have a map and i want to group this map to a list that contains keys of duplicate items like below.

map: {1=a, 2=b, 3=a, 4=b, 5=c, 6=b, 7=a}

expected result: [[1,3,7], [2,4,6], [5]]

I try below code and it gives [[1=a, 3=a, 7=a], [2=b, 4=b, 6=b], [5=c]] but i do not want values.

```
val list1 = map.entries.groupBy {
        it.value
    }.values.toList()


    println(list1)
```

Comment: what exactly is the output you expect? why don't you use a datastructure that doesn't allow duplicates? the result is exactly what it should be the way you wrote your code.

Comment: @Stultuske indicate output as expected result: [[1,3,7], [2,4,6], [5]]. I just want key of same items in an array. Don't want to remove duplicates so did not use datastructure.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add valueTransform function

```
val list = map.entries.groupBy({ it.value }, { it.key }).values.toList()
```

Comment: This looks cleaner. 

Comment: `values` returns a `Collection`, so if you're not bothered about a list specifically, you can drop the `toList()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
Map<Object,List<Object>> resultMap = map.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Map.Entry::getValue,Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
    
    System.out.println(resultMap.values());
```

Comment: This is ok but there is api level restrictions in android.